# Output speex encode in a file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio-recording, speex

I'm using the script found on this blog [Google speech recognition with python](http://campus.albion.edu/squirrel/2012/03/01/google-speech-recognition-with-python/) (I give any credit to author).

```
    import sys
    import pyaudio, speex
    import numpy as np  # just for doing a standard deviation for audio level checks
    import urllib2
    import wave

    e = speex.Encoder()
    e.initialize(speex.SPEEX_MODEID_WB)
    d = speex.Decoder()
    d.initialize(speex.SPEEX_MODEID_WB)

    chunk = 320 # tried other numbers... some don't work
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    bytespersample=2
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 16000 # "wideband" mode for speex. May work with 8000. Haven't tried it.

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    # Start the stream to record the audio
    stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
                    channels = CHANNELS,
                    rate = RATE,
                    input = True,
                    output = True,
                    frames_per_buffer = chunk)

    print "Listening. Recording will start when some sound is heard."

    threshold = 200  # Adjust this to be slightly above the noise level of your recordings.
    nquit = 40 # number of silent frames before terminating the program
    nover = 0
    keepgoing = True
    spxlist=[]  # list of the encoded speex packets/frames
    while keepgoing:
      data = stream.read(chunk) # grab 320 samples from the microphone
      spxdata = e.encode(data) # encode using the speex dll
      print "Length encoded: %d"%len(spxdata) # print the length, after encoding. Can't exceed 255!
      spxlist.append(spxdata)
      a=np.frombuffer(data,np.int16) # convert to numpy array to check for silence or audio
      audiolevel=np.std(a)
      if audiolevel < threshold:  # too quiet
        nover+=1
      else:
        nover=0

      if nover >= nquit:
        keepgoing=False


      print '%2.1f (%d%% quiet)'%(audiolevel, nover*100/nquit)

    print "Too quiet. I'm stopping now."
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
    fullspx=''.join(spxlist)  # make a string of all the header-ized speex packets
    out_file = open("test.spx","wb")
    out_file.write(fullspx)
    out_file.close()
```

As you can see I slightly modify the script to make it write and output file in .spx, but it dosen't work.

Any advice?

Thanks for your help.

Edit:
I'm running this script under an Ubuntu-linux machine.

Comment: Is the output file test.spx simply empty? Note that in contrast to the original program, you're never sending your data to that Google speech recognition url...

Comment: No the output it's not empty, but I can't open that file with any program (even with audacity or vlc), unsupported format or similar. oh... I forgot to mention, I don't want send data to Google right now.

Comment: I think the only "program" which is supposed to process it is Google's speech recognition. It's constructed for it.

Comment: Yeah.. I had the same thought, but I can't understand where mistakes are. Maybe reading more carefully speex API will help!